# VS 2013 SDK: How to add a line separator in a CommandBarPopup menu?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-sdk

In **C#** or else **VB.Net**, using a Visual Studio **Package**, how I could add a separator line to a `CommandBarPopup` menu?.

I've tried the solution given by @**Carlos J. Quintero** in this question:

**[How do I insert a separator line between multiple Add-In commands in a menu command bar?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f26acf64-0ee6-4947-84e4-a7a0ded9d636/how-do-i-insert-a-separator-line-between-multiple-addin-commands-in-a-menu-command-bar?forum=vsx)**

Using this code:

```
    Private Sub AddSeparatorLine(ByRef cmndBarPopup As CommandBarPopup,
                                 ByVal index As Integer)

        Dim tempCommandBarButton As CommandBarButton =
            DirectCast(cmndBarPopup.Controls.Add(MsoControlType.msoControlButton, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, index, True), CommandBarButton)

        With tempCommandBarButton 
            .BeginGroup = True
            .Visible = True
            .Enabled = False
        End With

    End Sub
```

However, it just adds a blank space (a button without name) to do the separator, isn't a separator line.

This is the kind of separator line that I expect:

[image]

But this is what I got:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating the user interface for packages is totally different than creating it for add-ins. For packages almost everything is done in the .vsct file. Line separators separate groups, so if you want a line separator you need to declare a new group. See [How to Create Reusable Groups of Buttons](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb164663.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understood properly how to do it. I've created an empty vs package (instead of default command menu template because my intention is not add a command under the "Tools" menu, just the code editor contextmenu) then it doesn't comes with an vsct file and a copy/paste of a vsct file is not enough, also I'm generating the menu and buttons at execution time (that's the right way to create them for context menu?). Si pudieras explicarme un poco más, muchas gracias de todas formas.

Comment: You absolutely need to use .vsct file to create the commands and user interface (buttons, toolbars, etc.). While it is possible to create them using DTE (like an add-in), it is not recommended at all. So, the question is how to do what you want using a .vsct file. You need 1) A group for your buttons and 2) A parent for that group. The parent for the code editor context menu is:       <CommandPlacement guid="guidYourVSPackageCmdSet" id="YourGroup" priority="0x600">
         <Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDM_VS_CTXT_CODEWIN"/>
      </CommandPlacement>

Comment: please could you provide an official MSDN url reference to see that guid?. "XXX_CodeWin" reffres only to the code editor of a Windows Forms project?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.package.vsmenus.idm_vs_ctxt_codewin.aspx

Comment: To guess guids/ids of parents for groups, and existing groups guids/ids is extremely frustrating. I always go the code of my package to provide answers like IDM_VS_CTXT_CODEWIN

Answer (score 1):

You should define the symbols, buttons and groups in a vsct file, even for context menu's. I would create all possible items and decide which ones to enable/make visible at execution time. Alternatively you could use the [DynamicItemStart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166492.aspx) command flag for this.

I would like to advise you to take a look at this [article](http://dotneteers.net/blogs/divedeeper/archive/2008/03/02/LearnVSXNowPart14.aspx), which explains the specifics of working with vspackages quite well. This is actually one part of an entire series which helped me a lot when I needed vspackage info that was hard to find elsewhere. Take a look at the "Separating command groups in a menu" section for your problem.

> UPDATE

This is the guid for **Visual Studio 2013**

[image]

### VSDebug Message

Menu data:

```
Guid = {D309F791-903F-11D0-9EFC-00A0C911004F}
GuidID = 4
CmdID = 1037
Type = 0x00000400
Flags = 0x00000000
NameLoc = Code Window
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, good thing to know now that I should create the contextmenu from an VSCT file, but then how I move the menu onto the code editor contextmenu?, I imagine that I should use the proper guid for that, but I revised all the guids in the MSDN guids page and I've tested almost all guids without success, could you please supply a simple example of an VSCT file (its symbols and guids) to create and insert a menu inside the code editor window contextmenu? or at least the necessary guid that reffers to that contextmenu?

Comment: There is a debug hook (available since VS 2005) that lets you identify the guid of almost any menu item in Visual Studio. Unfortunately this is often the easiest way to find out the correct guid. See this older [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dr._ex/archive/2007/04/17/using-enablevsiplogging-to-identify-menus-and-commands-with-vs-2005-sp1.aspx) for further instructions. The article I linked in my answer contains complete examples of working vsct files, I suggest you check it out.

Comment: Thankyou,but together with a GUID I need an ID to replace the `<Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDM_VS_MENU_TOOLS"/>` for this else `<Parent guid="guidCodeEditorMenu" id="???"/>` how I do thtat? what symbol value is necessary for this "id"?. I've read the article you linked but nothing, I also tried the symbols they use, I'm doing things right?. My menu doesn't appears.

Comment: In the link you provided in your comment, says that the guid+cmdid composes a GUID:ID, however, I've tried the cmdid 1037 (or 0x040D) and did nothing, menu doesn't appears in the contextmenu.

Comment: I also tried with the text editor's ids from here without success... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc807687.aspx